# A virtual printer that outputs to stdout or TCP

Tags: windows, device-driver

I am looking for a piece of software that acts as a print driver, and passes the data to my application, either in standard out or TCP or even just dumps it in a file somewhere.

Would be extra nice if there would be some configuration available (like enabling landscape, perforating etc)

Thanks a bunch

Comment: You'll have a much easier time playing with printer output programmatically via Linux, specifically setting up Samba and providng a network shared "printer" - Check this out for some ideas - https://linuxgazette.net/issue79/fraile.html

Comment: Just curious. Is this for debug trace, from an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1
[image: senter image description here]
Step 2
[image]
Step 3
[image]
Step 4
[image]

Your option are minimal here, but you do get portrait or landscape.
[image]

Changing the printer driver here:
[image: Driver change]
May result in better options.